# How to pass selected value as argument to the helper method

Tags: reactjs

How to update state from selectedValue? or How to pass selected value as argument to the helper method

```
class SelectParker extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue: "",
    values: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          values: json,
        });
      });
  }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">Select Parker</div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <div>
            <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              {this.state.values.map((obj) => {
                return (
                  <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
                    {obj.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectParker;
```

How to pass selected value as argument to the helper method to update the state

Comment: i think you have to use `event.target.value`
<select onChange={handleOnChange} ...

Comment: its getting undefined- thanks

Comment: sorry, try: `<select onChange={this.handleOnChange} >`

Comment: If I did not add this prefix to handleChnage then the event is not working, i did it but the problem is returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your handleOnChange method in the select element and then pass the selectedValue as the value of the select.

So this would work:

```js
import React from 'react';

class SelectParker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue: "",
    values: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          values: json,
        });
      });
  }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: event.target.value
    })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">Select Parker</div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <div>
            <select value={this.state.selectedValue} className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" onChange={this.handleOnChange}>
              {this.state.values.map((obj: any) => {
                return (
                  <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
                    {obj.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SelectParker;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    handleOnChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({selectedValue:event.target.value});
  };

<select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"
    onChange={handleOnChange}
    >
                  {this.state.values.map((obj) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={obj.id} value={obj.id}>
                        {obj.name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                </select>
```

Comment: Its getting undefined

Comment: can you look this example https://codepen.io/codyswartz/pen/QWqYNrY

Comment: @Neo It should be this.handleOnChange not handleOnChange.